# Dockerfile with java 17

Tags: java, docker, java-17

I want to crate docker image with java 17 and maven. My idea was to use openjdk image with java 17 but I see that opendjk is **deprecated**.

1. What does it mean that is deprecated? It will work but without update?
2. What image can I use for it? is there any one ready with java 17 and maven ?
3. Can I use it for comercial purposes?

Comment: current distributions: https://sdkman.io/jdks, there should also be images availlable on dockerhub

Comment: You can always use bare bone image of whatever distro you like as a `Dockerfile` base and then simply install whatever version of `JDK` you like. `JDK17` is supposed to stay for a quite a long time now: `30 Sep 2029`. Take a look here for an example: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile

Comment: Ok I se your Dockerfile but openjdk is deprecated, what does it mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a good article:

> https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2022/09/16/updating-docker-hubs-openjdk-image
>
> For many years, the official Docker Hub image builders took OpenJDK
> Java SE update binaries from [Eclipse Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/) and other locations to
> build their own image. But in July 2022, the Docker Hub image builders
> announced the deprecation of this popular image.
>
> Now, Docker asks users to obtain their builds of OpenJDK, either from
> a commercial Java vendor or directly from the Adoptium project. There
> will be no further updates to the existing OpenJDK image, so users
> risk falling behind with functional and security updates to their Java
> SE usage unless they move to an alternate provider. I believe the
> [official Eclipse Temurin image](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin) maintained by the Adoptium project is
> the obvious choice for a replacement image.

In other words, the only thing that's "deprecated" is the prebuilt Docker image.  Not OpenJDK, and certainly not Java 17.

It simply means that *you're* responsible for adding the JDK of your choice to whatever Docker image you decide to use.

Another alternative - which the same link goes on to suggest - is getting an image from the Adoptium project:

> Adoptium is a project dedicated to building, testing, and distributing
> up-to-date and ready-to-use OpenJDK binaries under an open source
> license. Adoptium calls their builds of OpenJDK, Temurin. They are
> available across a broad range of processors and operating systems.
> These Temurin binaries have over half a billion downloads and earned
> the trust of enterprise production environments worldwide. A
> vendor-independent working group based at the Eclipse software
> foundation leads Adoptium.
>
> The Adoptium community provides binaries built directly from OpenJDK
> source code. These Temurin binaries are available as direct downloads,
> installers, or container images and are faithful representations of
> the OpenJDK update source built under controlled conditions.
>
> The official Docker Hub Temurin images contain the latest releases of
> the OpenJDK updates for several Java SE versions, thoroughly tested
> with various applications. The images work as direct drop-in
> replacements for the OpenJDK images. Some OpenJDK images already
> contain Temurin binaries.

Comment: OpenJDK on Adoptium(Temurin) is opensource? Can I use it for commercial purposes?

Comment: If I download docker image with openjdk Temurin, on what Linux distro does Temurin base on ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this Dockerfile for Java 17

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim AS build

COPY pom.xml mvnw ./
COPY .mvn .mvn
RUN ./mvnw dependency:resolve

COPY src src
RUN ./mvnw package

FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
WORKDIR demo
COPY --from=build target/*.jar demo.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "demo.jar"]
```

Comment: You are correct.  There should be *NO* problem using Java 17.  For that matter, *ANY* version of Java (even Java 1.2!) should work has long as the application's .class files were compiled on that version (or lower).

Comment: ok but what about openjdk, there is a info that openjdk is deprecated, what does it men? can I use it?
https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk   - DEPRECATION NOTICE

Comment: "openjdk" (https://openjdk.org/) is *NOT* deprecated.  Only the Docker images with pre-installed OpenJDK that had previously been available from DockerHub.  The alternatives are 1) simply use a different base image, install your own JDK, and use that (custom) image, or 2) consider downloading an [eclipse-temurin](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin) Docker image or equivalent (see my response below).

Comment: @paulsm4 If I want to use mvn in openjdk Temurin, I have to create Dockerfile and add/install to it, right?